# Insert a column chart that shows the number of values found in a range of rows

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula, pivot-table, countif

Assume I have data as follows:

```
Id; Author; Customer
Ticket 1; John; Alice
Ticket 2; John; Bob
Ticket 3; Ken; Charles
Ticket 4; Ken; Darren
```

(I use `;` to symbolize the end of the cell/column)

I then want to produce a column chart that has one column per unique value for the `Author` and the height of the column is the number of times that value occurs. In this example, I would have two columns (`John` and `Ken`) and each would be `2` in size.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want could be achieved with a PivotTable where `Author` is ROWS and Count of Author is Sigma VALUES then select the data and insert column chart:

[image: SO23219612 example]

Comment: Trying that out now. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: It worked just fine. It's fairly straightforward, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pnuts answer is brilliant and will give you what you need, from my understanding. As an alternative, you could build a summary table that you then graph, in which case a basic countif would suffice. In general, you'd summarize data on a separate sheet to your data source, but the scale of data would determine precisely how you'd do this. IN this example, I will include the summary data that Pnuts solution uses pivottables to produce on the same sheet as the source data.

In Cell A7\A8 I'd put John\Ken respectively (bigger solutions, I'd do on a separate sheet and use the 'remove duplicates' tool in Excel)
=countif($B$2:$B$5, A7)
then drag this down to A8, and then you could graph that.

I don't have the rep to post images, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I am just surprised we have to go through this middle step of summarizing data before actually displaying it. I had a SQL mind when I got down to doing this...